# Pattern matching lists of certain size or greater/less

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

Is there a way to specify a pattern that matches a List with a size greater (or less) or equal a certain value in Scala?

For example, if I want to apply the same action to all lists of size 3 or less:

```
list match {
    case Nil => op(list) 
    case x :: Nil => op(list)
    case x :: y :: Nil => op(list)
    case x :: y :: z :: Nil => op(list)
    case x :: tail => other(list)
}
```

Is there a way to reduce this to two cases?

Comment: i think it can be done with a guard ...case... if (tail.size >= x) =>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, although you'll need to reverse the order of the cases:

```
list match {
  case l @ (_ :: _ :: _ :: _) => other(l)
  case l => op(l)
}
```

Note that I've bound a new variable `l` to the list in the pattern instead of referring to `list`, and that I've used `_` when I don't need a variable. I'd suggest sticking to both of these practices, but the answer would work exactly the same without them.

Comment: I do not see the point of using such an obfuscated syntax when the guard condition does the job asked in the question.

Comment: @DenisR.: First, I was answering the question as asked, and second, I'm not sure this answer is actually less idiomatic than the guard condition when you're working with lists, where `length` is an expensive operation. If you want to avoid traversing the list (and you should), you'd have to write something like `case l if l.lengthCompare(3) > -1`, which is its own kind of awkward.

Comment: you are right about complexity and using lengthCompare.
I prefer this solution because the length is explicitely written and not written as a number of "_" -1.
Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you suggest to use `l` and avoid `list`? How would you make a separation in cases for: length 1, any length, and empty list?

Answer (score 13):

If you insist on using a pattern match (maybe you want to include more *match cases*?), you can use a **guard condition** for it:

```
list match {
    case l if(l.size <= 3) => op(l)
    case l => other(l)
}
```

Comment: Using lengthCompare would be more efficient to compare list length to 3

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with a plain old if / else??

```
if (list.length >= minimumLength)
  longer(list)
else
  shorter(list)
```

Comment: What if the list is really long? The match / case without using the length would be better...

Comment: I'm not sure what "really long" might be, but `Lists` have considerable size overhead per element held and are not strongly indicated for very large collections. They really have only one big virtue: very efficient head / tail decomposition.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with:

```
list.splitAt(len) match {
   case (xs, Nil) => other(xs)
   case (_, _) => op(list)
}
```

Also the complexity is `O(len)` thus even if list if long, `len` is deciding factor.

The above calls `op` if `list.size < len` else calls `other`